# Chef remote_file resource error Chef::Exceptions::ContentLengthMismatch

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

When downloading http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.7/src/haproxy-1.7.5.tar.gz file using `remote_file`

I got the following error:

```
[2017-05-16T09:31:36+00:00] INFO: AWS OpsWorks instance ******, Agent version 4023-20170402215230, Command: setup with id 521be6b3-f80a-476f-9964-17fcfe056bef
[2017-05-16T09:31:38+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /opt/aws/opsworks/current
One version per cookbook
data_bags at /var/lib/aws/opsworks/data.internal/data_bags
nodes at /

[2017-05-16T09:31:38+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2017-05-16T09:31:38+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.13.37 ***
[2017-05-16T09:31:38+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux


[2017-05-16T09:33:35+00:00] INFO: Processing yum_package[zlib-devel] action install (omise::haproxy line 13)
[2017-05-16T09:33:35+00:00] INFO: Processing remote_file[/tmp/haproxy-1.7.3.tar.gz] action create (omise::haproxy line 19)

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'remote_file[/tmp/haproxy-1.7.3.tar.gz]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::ContentLengthMismatch
---------------------------------------
Response body length 3273 does not match HTTP Content-Length header 1737006.
This error is most often caused by network issues (proxies, etc) outside of chef-client.

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/runs/521be6b3-f80a-476f-9964-17fcfe056bef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/omise/recipes/haproxy.rb

19: remote_file "/tmp/haproxy-#{version}.tar.gz" do
20:   source "http://www.haproxy.org/download/#{version.gsub(/[.][0-9]+$/,'')}/src/haproxy-#{version}.tar.gz"
21:   checksum node["omise"]["haproxy"]["checksum"]
22:   notifies :run, "bash[install_haproxy]", :immediately
23:   not_if { sys_version && sys_version >= version }
24: end
25:
```

Even though, current Chef client on Opsworks is version `12.13.37`, I am not sure if it's related to this issue https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5198 but it looks similar.

Anyone experience this issue at the moment?

Also, any workaround or help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would try doing the request from the node itself, I would bet those 3273 bytes are an error page of some kind. Not likely to be compression related unless you've got a magic algorithm for turning 1.7M into 3k.

Comment: @coderanger Ah, thanks.